# Convert conditional variable to date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a CTE that splits rows into new ones based on the lengh of the period (start to end dates), this code is currently printing the **splitted new dates** into the full datetime in US format.

This:

```
SELECT --VARIABLES
newBEG = CASE n WHEN 0  THEN f ELSE bp END
FROM --TABLE
```

Prints this:

```
2017-12-26 00:00:00.000
```

The original dates I can easily convert them in the format I want (`DD/MM/YYYY`) using the `CONVERT()` function because it's just the varible without changes:

This:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),f, 103)
```

Prints this:

```
26/12/2017
```

But considering `newBEG` it's a calculated variable I'm unable to put the entire code inside the `CONVERT()` function, is any way -inside the same select i'm using- convert the variable to the `103` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CASE n WHEN 0 THEN f ELSE bp END, 103) as newBEG 
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!. Do you know if I could convert or handle these variables into datetimes or similiar so I can use `ORDER BY`?